# How do I plot the following in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to plotting in R so I ask for your help. Say I have the following matrix.

```
mat1 <- matrix(seq(1:6), 3)
dimnames(mat1)[[2]] <- c("x", "y")
dimnames(mat1)[[1]] <- c("a", "b", "c")
mat1
  x y
a 1 4
b 2 5
c 3 6
```

I want to plot this, where the x-axis contains each rowname (a, b, c) and the y-axis is the value of each rowname (a = 1 and 4, b = 2 and 5, c = 3 and 6). Any help would be appreciated!

```
|     o
|   o x
| o x
| x
|_______
  a b c
```

Comment: BTW, good job on reading the links I gave you and rewriting your question in a much better form. As you can see below from the answers below and your upvotes, it paid dividends! :)

Comment: I will get the hang of it :) Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one way using base graphics:

```
plot(c(1,3),range(mat1),type = "n",xaxt ="n")
points(1:3,mat1[,2])
points(1:3,mat1[,1],pch = "x")
axis(1,at = 1:3,labels = rownames(mat1))
```

[image]

*Edited to include different plotting symbol*

Comment: Is there any way to make the x-axis labels vertical?

Comment: @user1854603 Do you mean the y axis labels? Otherwise I'm note sure what you mean.

Comment: @user1854603 Play around with the `las` argument, like this: `plot(1:3, las=1); plot(1:3, las=2)` and so on up to `las=4`. (FWIW, `axis()` also takes an `las` argument.)

Comment: @joran Like, the "a" would look like it's on its side. The rownames of the actual matrix I'm using are several letters long, and cramming it as is causes overlap.

Comment: @user1854603 Josh's comment has got you covered, then.

Answer (score 10):

`matplot()` was designed for data in just this format:

```
matplot(y = mat1, pch = c(4,1), col = "black", xaxt ="n",
        xlab = "x-axis", ylab = "y-axis")
axis(1, at = 1:nrow(mat1), labels = rownames(mat1))             ## Thanks, Joran
```

[image]

Comment: ...and you can do the same thing as I did with `xaxt` and `axis` to label the x axis with letters.

Comment: @joran -- Good. I added that and a hat-tip to you.

Comment: So something like `matplot(mat1, xaxt='n'); axis(1, at=1:nrow(mat1), labels=rownames(mat1));`

Answer (score 6):

And finally, a lattice solution

```
library(lattice)
dfmat <- as.data.frame(mat1)
xyplot( x + y ~ factor(rownames(dfmat)), data=dfmat, pch=c(4,1), cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for poor old neglected lattice--which I still find to be the best data-exploration tool for plots.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman - For my personal education, what does lattice have over ggplot as a data-exploration tool?

Comment: @DrewSteen I find the syntax to be a little more intuitive for slicing and dicing up data.  `ggplot` has `qplot`, but I still find lattice functions faster to add grouping-by-color and grouping-by-trellising.  Also shingles are brilliant: `dfmat <- data.frame( x=seq(18), y=seq(18), z= rep(seq(3),6), a=runif(18) ); xyplot( x+y~factor(z)|equal.count(a,3),data=dfmat )`

Comment: @DrewSteen lattice is also faster than ggplot, especially for faceted plots, at least for the time being ...

Comment: That's certainly a useful trait!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in base graphics, but if you're going to use R for much more than this I think it is worth getting to know the `ggplot2` package. Note that `ggplot2` only takes data frames - but then, it is often more useful to keep your data in data frames rather than matrices.

```
d <- as.data.frame(mat1) #convert to a data frame
d$cat <- rownames(d) #add the 'cat' column
dm <- melt(d, id.vars)
dm #look at dm to get an idea of what melt is doing

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dm, aes(x=cat, y=value, shape=variable)) #define the data the plot will use, and the 'aesthetics' (i.e., how the data are mapped to visible space)
  + geom_point() #represent the data with points
```

[image]